# Command and error

Tags: perl, perl-module

i have install local Lib and when I try to install the module it gives me error that I dont have permission on install the  module .

You may have to su to root to install the package.

Following is the step I used to download local::Lib

```
-bash-3.2$ perl Makefile.PL --bootstrap
*** Module::AutoInstall configuration finished.
Writing Makefile for local::lib
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.jsonake 


make test
```

All tests successful.
   Files=8, Tests=35,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.06 usr  0.02 sys +  0.28 cusr  0.08 csys =  0.44 CPU)
   Result: PASS
   -bash-3.2$

```
make install
-bash-3.2$ make install
Manifying blib/man3/POD2::PT_BR::local::lib.3pm
lib/POD2/PT_BR/local/lib.pod:1: Unknown command paragraph "=encoding utf8"
Manifying blib/man3/lib::core::only.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/local::lib.3pm
lib/local/lib.pm:551: Unknown command paragraph "=encoding utf8"
Manifying blib/man3/POD2::DE::local::lib.3pm
lib/POD2/DE/local/lib.pod:1: Unknown command paragraph "=encoding utf8"
Appending installation info to /homes/ar312/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-  multi/perllocal.pod

echo 'eval $(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)' >>~/.bashrc
```

Comment: So, did you try to do it as a root?

Comment: I dont have sudo rights on the server thats why I am tring to use local library. Is there any way.

Comment: What's the content of `~/.bashrc`? The documentation contains the instruction: **After writing your shell configuration file, be sure to re-read it to get the changed settings into your current shell's environment.** Did you do so?

Comment: -bash-3.2$ ~/.bashrc
-bash: /homes/ar312/.bashrc: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

> *`/homes/ar312/.bashrc: Permission denied`*

There's the problem. Work-around: run

```
eval $(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)
```

manually in each login session.